# Downloading pictures in a list of websites

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
urls <- data.frame(c("https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1212/08", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1212/09", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/07", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/08", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/09", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/07", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/08", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/09"))
```

To download every picture in each website, I created this code with the help of some folks in StackOverflow:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

for (url in urls) {

  webpage <- html_session(url)
  link.titles <- webpage %>% html_nodes("img")
  img.url <- link.titles %>% html_attr("src")
  download.file(img.url, url, ".jpg", mode = "wb")

}
```

But, it returns this error:

```
Error: is.character(url) is not TRUE
```

Strangely, running it without the loop function works fine:

```
url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1692/09"
webpage <- html_session(url)
link.titles <- webpage %>% html_nodes("img")
img.url <- link.titles %>% html_attr("src")
download.file(img.url, "test.jpg", mode = "wb")
```

I'm looking to download every picture in each website.

Comment: I received two negative points from posting this question. Could someone give me an explanation what I've done wrong here?

Comment: You were trying to make file names that start with ""https://ec.europa.eu/cons"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but it appears each image is the same, not sure if that's the intention.

```
urls <- c("https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1212/08", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1212/09", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/07", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/08", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/09", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/07", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/08", 
                     "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/09")

for (url in 1:length(urls)) {

    print(url)
    webpage <- html_session(urls[url])
    link.titles <- webpage %>% html_nodes("img")
    img.url <- link.titles %>% html_attr("src")
    download.file(img.url, paste0(url,".jpg"), mode = "wb")

}
```

I changed the urls from a data frame to a character vector, if you wanted to keep it in a df, then do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(urls_df)){...}
```

Then have to refer to it like so in the body

```
webpage <- html_session(urls_df[i,1]) # Refers to the i'th row column 1
```

I also changed the arguments to download.file, which was different from your loop to the single solution.

To download all the images:

```
for (url in 1:length(urls)) {

    print(url)
    webpage <- html_session(urls[url])
    link.titles <- webpage %>% html_nodes("img")
    img.url <- link.titles %>% html_attr("src")

    for(j in 1:length(img.url)){

        download.file(img.url[j], paste0(url,'.',j,".jpg"), mode = "wb")
    }

}
```

If you only want the images in the body, looking at the structure, you could create an `if` condition that only initiates a download if `length(img.url) > 1`

Comment: Thank you. Would there be a way to skip those pages that do not contain an image? I get the following error: `scheme not supported in URL 'NA'` when I change the `download.file(img.url, paste0(url,".jpg"), mode = "wb")` to `download.file(img.url[3], paste0(url,".jpg"), mode = "wb")`

Comment: I would recommend downloading all of them by iterating over the `img.url`. I'll update my answer code. Then, if there is only 1, you can just toss those out as it's most likely the header image.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is reading your urls in the data frame as factors - you need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` like this,

```
urls <- data.frame(c("https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1212/08", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1212/09", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/07", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/08", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1213/09", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/07", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/08", 
              "https://ec.europa.eu/consumers/consumers_safety/safety_products/rapex/alerts/?event=viewProduct&reference=1214/09"),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: For the original file where I am sampling from, I've already applied `stringAsFactors`, but it still gives me the error. In the reproducible example, it gives `Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`

Comment: hmm, I am not seeing that error (in fact, I am receiving an unrelated curl error, even when running the final chunk that you specify works fine for you).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into my question. I appreciate your efforts and time very much.